# How do I use getopt with the null file handle (<>) in Perl?

Tags: perl, getopt

I have a script which does some basic awk like filtering using a `while(<>)` loop. I want the script to be able to display usage and version, but otherwise assume all arguments are files. How do I combine getopt with the <> operator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have mentioned, [Getopt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html) is the prefered module. It has been around since Perl 3.x.

There's a lot of *options*, and it can take a while to get use to the syntax, but it does exactly what you want:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;
use feature qw(say);
use Pod::Usage;

my ( $version, $help );   #Strict, we have to predeclare these:

GetOptions(
   'help'    => \$help,
   'version' => \$version,
) or pod2usage ( -message => "Invalid options" );
```

That's all there is to it. When the `Getoptions` subroutine runs, it will parse your command line (the `@ARGV` array) for anything that starts with a `-` or `--`. It will process those, and when it comes to either a double dash by itself, or an option not starting with a dash, it will assume those are files and it's done processing. At that point, all of the option strings (and their parameters) have been *shifted* out of the `@ARGSV` array, and you're left with your files:

```
if ( $help ) {
    pod2usage;
}
if ( $version ) {
    say "Version 1.23.3";
    exit;
}

while ( my $file = <>) {
    ...
}
```

`Getopts::Long` is part of the standard Perl installation, so it should always be available to you.

I know many people are wary of using these modules because they think they're not *standard Perl*, but they are just as much a part of Perl as commands like `print` and `chomp`. Perl comes with over 500 of them and they're yours to use.

Comment: Actually there are a few modules that don't come with Perl, that I would consider "*standard Perl*". [LWP](https://metacpan.org/release/libwww-perl) is one example.

Comment: There are certain modules I would love to see included in a standard Perl installation: `LWP`, `Readonly`, Net::LDAP, and some JSON and XML module. I do a lot of scripting on servers under the control of others. Getting any optional CPAN module installed is a pain. The servers at my current company are on Perl 5.8.9. I can't even use `say` or `autodie`. Fortunately, `Getopts::Long` is included.

Answer (score 7):

Getopt plays nicely with `@ARGV`. Example

```
use strict; use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use Getopt::Long;

GetOptions 'foo=s' => \my $foo;

say "foo=$foo";
say "ARGV:";
say for @ARGV;
```

Then:

```
$ perl test.pl --foo fooval --bar
Unknown option: bar
foo=fooval
ARGV:
$ perl test.pl --foo fooval bar
foo=fooval
ARGV:
bar
$ perl test.pl --foo fooval -- --bar
foo=fooval
ARGV:
--bar
```

Summary:

- Any items in `@ARGV` after the switches are simply left there.
- This works as expected for normal filenames (that don't start with a hyphen-minus).
- You can always use a `--` to abort parsing of switches.

Answer (score 4):

This works as expected for me.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);

my %opt;
GetOptions(\%opt, qw(help)) or die;

die 'usage' if $opt{help};

while (<>) {
    print;
}
```